# use algorithm to generate decompositions in 3NF

Tags: database-normalization

I would like to use the algorithm to generate decompositions in 3NF
with retention of dependencies.

R(ABCDEFGH)
F={a->b, abcd->e,ef->g,ef->h,acdf->e,acdf->g}

the only key is acdf. I apply the algorithm to find the 3fn,
eliminating extraneous attributes and redundant dependencies. I get:

F={a->b, acd->e, ef->g, ef->h}

if I create these tables:
tab1 (AB)
tab2 (ACDE)
tab3 (EFG)
TAB4 (EFH)

Am I in normal third form? No. it seems to me that I can't
never decompose it into a 3fn because of a-> b.
So what does that mean, that the algorithm isn't sure which I am
do you find a decomposition in 3 fn?

Comment: "because of a-> b" is not clear. You need to clearly explain your reasoning, including giving & referring to a definition of 3NF.

Comment: Why would you "create these tables"? Per what algorithm or other justification? PS You probably mean something like that the 2nd F is a canonical cover. "eliminating extraneous attributes and redundant dependencies" is not clear or helpful. And your last sentence is garbled & doesn't make sense.